# Nonsensical output stream during the usage of "getchar()" and "EOF"

Tags: c, eof, getchar, putchar

I have been experimenting with `getchar()`, `putchar()` and have been trying to use `EOF`. Below is the snippet of code I have been experimenting with.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();

    while(c != EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d\n", EOF);
        c = getchar();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> **Input: -**
>
> a
>
> **Expected output: -**
>
> a `//Due to putchar()`
>
> -1 `//Value of EOF`
>
> `//Now the cursor should come in next line and wait for next character.`
>
> **Output getting in real time: -**
>
> a
>
> -1
>
> -1
>
> `//Cursor waiting for next character.`

I am not able to comprehend the reason why the output is showing `-1` two times.

Comment: If you remove the EOF printing will it still show that one -1? And is it printing another newline between the -1s?

Comment: `//Now the cursor should come in next line and wait for next character.` The second loop *doesn't wait* but reads a newline. Did you notice the extra blank line in the output?

Comment: @MaxxikCZ No it will not show `-1`, but it will then have two more `\n` in output stream.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you.Please point out the fact in form of an answer, I shall accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code comment says

```
//Now the cursor should come in next line and wait for next character.
```

But the second loop *doesn't wait*. It reads the newline that was already entered, and this is shown by the extra blank line in the output.

Answer (score 1):

After the first input before the loop

```
c = getchar();
```

the input buffer contains the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter.

So in the while loop there are outputted

```
a
```

and

```
-1
```

due to the statement

```
printf("%d\n", EOF);
```

After that this statement in the loop

```
c = getchar();
```

reads the new line character that is present in the input buffer. So again this statement

```
printf("%d\n", EOF);
```

outputs

```
-1
```